# Android Как объединить одинаковые ресурсы для разных разрешений экрана

Tags: android

У меня есть реальная задача - есть два макета 800 на 480 (телефон - портретный вид) и 1280 на 800 (планшет - планшетный вид). Вообще все картинки одинаковые - но как объединить ресурсы в одну папку не знаю
Я сейчас делаю так есть две папки drawable-800x480 и drawable-1280x800 из первой копирую во втрорую а как сделать наподобие  drawable-800x480-or-1280x800?

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

картинки должны быть в разных папках. они уже налету будут подбиратся и оптимизироватся для конкретного экрана

Comment: Это понятно - просто, получаеся, что в двух разных папках одни и теже одинаковые файлы - увеличивается вес файла

Comment: да, но если ты можешь пожертвовать качеством некоторых картинок - можешь все держать в одном варианте. может получится сделать качественную верстку грамотно применив 9patch или правильно разместив леяуты. так же попробуй поэксперементировать с разрешением картинок может быть .jpg будет меньше .png и размер программы увеличится совсем незначительно. попробуй все картинки высокого качества положить в папку для самого большого разрешения, возможно будет нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите положить все картинки в 1 каталог пихайте их все в `/res/drawable`, вы получите экономию места, но пожертвуете качеством картинок и скоростью работы, поскольку для разных разрешений ось вынуждена будет сама масштабировать и не факт, что качество и скорость масштабирования понравится юзеру.